# How to load a page with a redirect into an iframe

Tags: redirect, iframe, affiliate

I have an affiliate site where I redirect users to external sites via a link. This link triggers a redirect on the external page. 
The problem now is that when I load that page into an iframe on my own website there is no page loaded into the iframe at all.

Why?

Here's the iframe which I load on my website:

```
<iframe id="frame_content" name="frame_content" width="100%" style="height: calc(100% - 150px);" noresize="noresize" src="http://www.trouwartikelen.nl/huwelijk/?tt=2409_308109_134602_&r=http://www.trouwartikelen.nl/taart-serveerset-hartvormige-schep.html?utm_source=tradetracker&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_content=trouwartikelennl&utm_campaign=tradetracker" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iframe loaded as well with me, i've tried multiple browsers and platforms.

The only browser that does problems is `google chrome` with `adblock plus` extension. and when i disable this extension, chrome render your iframe as well too.

Comment: Ah, thanks, now it works! One more question: when I follow all the shop checkout steps while the page is in the iframe I don't see the src of the iframe change to https. When I follow the same steps outside the iframe the site does use https. Does this mean when loading the checkout process in the iframe the src attribute of the iframe is just not updated but the site is still securely handling the payment? Or how do I check whether the page is loaded securely? Thanks!

Comment: Your `src` starts with `http`... just change it to `https`.